# How to solve fourth order differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have a differential equation of this type:

```
y[x] - 1 - 2*l^2*y''[x] + l^4*y''''[x] == 0
```

(where `l` is a parameter and `l>=0`),

with boundary condtions that needs to be satisfied:

```
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[±∞] == 0, y''[±∞] == 0
```

The solution to this differential equation is:

```
y[x_] := 1 - Exp[-Abs[x]/l]*(1 + Abs[x]/l)
```

but I can't get it right. (I added a graph of solution function for `l=0.5`)

When I try to use `DSolve` (with 4 initial conditions because it's a fourth ordered differential equation) I get an error saying "For some branches of the general solution, unable to compute the limit at the given points. Some of the solutions may be lost."

```
DSolve[{y[x] - 1 - 2*l^2*y''[x] + l^4*y''''[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
        y'[0] == 0, y'[∞] == 0, y''[∞] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

I don't understand how this solution was obtained.

Can anyone help me?[image]

Comment: Simpson, you've been a member for 1.5 year, please make some effort to learn [formatting your post properly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Also, please show us how you tried `DSolve` so we can give pointed advice.

Comment: An elliptic 4th order boundary values problem with six boundary conditions sounds fishy. Btw., you can eliminate `l` by the substitution $ x \to l \, x$.

Comment: Also, there should be certain constraint for $l$, for example, when $l=-1$ the b.c. at infinity won't be satisfied: `Limit[y'[x] /. 
   y -> (Function[x, #1] &)[Simplify[1 - (E^(-(Abs[x]/l)) (l + Abs[x]))/l, x > 0]] /. 
  l -> -1, x -> \[Infinity]]`

Comment: @J. M . is computer-less: Could you edit  y[x_] too (Abs is from the original form of the question, where 6 boundary conditions were stated.)? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 What edit are you expecting? J.M. only improved the formatting. Except for the clarification $l\geq0$, the content of this question doesn't change so far.

Comment: @xzczd: E.g. RealAbs instead of Abs.

Comment: @user64494 Using `RealAbs` instead of `Abs` makes the code more convenient of course, but I don't think it's necessary, given the problem has already been defined on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: @xzczd: Comppare D[Abs[x], x] (*1*) with D[RealAbs[x],x] ( *x/RealAbs[x] *). Hope I am clear.

Comment: @user64494 I know, and that's what I mean by _convenient_. `Abs` makes programming harder, but it's not wrong: `FullSimplify[D[Abs[x], x], x \[Element] Reals]`.

Comment: @xzczd:Sorry, but FullSimplify[D[Abs[x], x], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals] 
 produces  ( *1* ).

Comment: @user64494 The output is `Sign[x]` in both _v9_ and _v11.2_. BTW another possible solution is `PiecewiseExpand`: `D[PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], x \[Element] Reals], x]`

Comment: @xzczd: I work in 11.3. The command  D[PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals], x] produces  $$\begin{cases}
 -1 & x<0 \\
 1 & x>0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: @user64494 Yes, the output of `D[PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], Assumptions -> x [Element] Reals], x]` is not that concise compared to `RealAbs`, but it should be enough in many (if not most) cases. As mentioned above, `Abs` is indeed less convenient, but I don't think it's necessary to edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $l=0$, the solution is clearly $y(x)=1$:

```
eq = y[x] - 1 - 2 l^2 y''[x] + l^4 y''''[x] == 0;  
Solve[eq /. l -> 0, y[x]]
(* {{y[x] -> 1}} *)
```

And it's the limit for the given solution:

```
Limit[1 - Exp[-Abs[x]/l]*(1 + Abs[x]/l), l -> 0, Assumptions -> x != 0]
(* 1 *)
```

Then let's focus on the $l>0$ case. We know `DSolve` cannot handle boundary condition (b.c.) at infinity directly, so we first solve with the 2 b.c.s at $x=0$:

```
generalsol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{eq, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y, x]

(* -((E^(-(x/l)) (-E^((x/l)) l + E^((2 x)/l) l - E^((2 x)/l) x - l C[1] + 
      E^((2 x)/l) l C[1] - 2 E^((2 x)/l) x C[1] - l x C[2] + E^((2 x)/l) l x C[2]))/l) *)
```

Calculate $y'(x)$ and transform it a bit:

```
Collect[D[generalsol, x], Exp[_]]
(* E^(x/l) (x/l^2 + C[1]/l + (2 x C[1])/l^2 - C[2] - (x C[2])/l) + 
   E^(-(x/l)) (-(C[1]/l) + C[2] - (x C[2])/l) *)
```

Let's consider $x\in(0,\infty)$ first, it's clear that the coefficient of `E^(x/l)` term should be `0` when $l>0$, or $y'(\infty)=0$ won't be satisfied:

```
cond1 = x/l^2 + C[1]/l + (2 x C[1])/l^2 - C[2] - (x C[2])/l == 0;
```

Similarly, we calculate $y''(x)$ and transform it a bit:

```
Collect[D[generalsol, x, x], Exp[_]]
(* E^(x/l) (1/l^2 + x/l^3 + (3 C[1])/l^2 + (2 x C[1])/l^3 - (2 C[2])/l - (x C[2])/l^2) + 
   E^(-(x/l)) (C[1]/l^2 - (2 C[2])/l + (x C[2])/l^2) *)
```

It's clear that the coefficient of `E^(x/l)` term should be `0`, or $y''(\infty)=0$ won't be satisfied:

```
cond2 = 1/l^2 + x/l^3 + (3 C[1])/l^2 + (2 x C[1])/l^3 - (2 C[2])/l - (x C[2])/l^2 == 0;
```

So `C[1]` and `C[2]` are determined:

```
coef = Flatten@Solve[{cond1, cond2}, C /@ {1, 2}]
(* {C[1] -> -1, C[2] -> -(1/l)} *)
```

And we find the solution for $x\in(0,\infty)$:

```
rightsolfunc[x_] = generalsol /. coef // FullSimplify
(* 1 - (E^(-(x/l)) (l + x))/l *)
```

We can repeat the process above to find solution for $x\in(-\infty,0)$ of course, but here I'll skip it because it's easy to notice `rightsolfunc[-x]` is the solution for $x\in(-\infty,0)$, thus the complete solution is:

```
sol = rightsolfunc@Abs@x
(* 1 - (E^(-(Abs[x]/l)) (l + Abs[x]))/l *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, y[x]=1 - (E^(-(RealAbs[x]/l)) (l +Real Abs[x]))/l does not satisfy eq at $x=0$. In order to clarify my point, plot y'''[x] on $ [−1,1]$.

Comment: @user64494 …Why it should? Notice this solution is just not a classical one, it's determined by 6 b.c.s while for a classical solution is just determined by 4. What's most important: this is the solution mentioned in the question i.e. the solution whose 2nd order derivative is not smooth at $x=0$ is exactly what OP is looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "this solution is just not a classical one" and give a reference? The third derivative y'''[x] is not continuous at the origin. Therefore, the fourth derivative does not exist at the origin at all.

Comment: @user64494 For example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154981/58219), see also the 1st paragraph of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution), you may search for _classical solution_, _weak solution_ to find more. As to the 4th order derivative, it actually exists, though it's not smooth. Finally, once again, the non-smooth derivative at $x=0$ just doesn't matter, because this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether y[x]=1 - (E^(-(RealAbs[x]/l)) (l +Real Abs[x]))/l is a weak solution of the problem under consideration. That claim should be based by formulas.

Comment: Comppare D[Abs[x], x] (1) with D[RealAbs[x],x] ( *x/RealAbs[x] *). Hope I am clear

Comment: @user64494 …Let's forget about those terminologies for a while and go a step back. With b.c.s `y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[∞] == 0, y''[∞] == 0` we find the solution for $[0,\infty)$ is `1 - (E^(-(x/l)) (l + x))/l`, and with `y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[-∞] == 0, y''[-∞] == 0` we find the solution for $(-\infty, 0)$ is `1 - (E^(x/l) (l - x))/l`, then why can't we shorten the solution to `1 - (E^(-(Abs[x]/l)) (l + Abs[x]))/l`? You may argue the notation is not religious, but such stuff exists everywhere. For example, how do you think about the function `WhenEvent` and the solutions produced by it?

Comment: This is not a question of notations, this is a question of notions. I repeat "It's unclear to me whether y[x]=1 - (E^(-(RealAbs[x]/l)) (l +Real Abs[x]))/l is a weak solution of the problem under consideration. That claim should be based by formulas ". The problem consists in the verification at the origin.

Comment: @user64494 This is not a question of notation nor notion. OP has a solution at hand, and he wants to know how this solution is deduced, so I showed a possible deduction, that's all. $y''(x)$ isn't smooth, so what? This is the _standard answer_ given by OP. What's the correct name for the solution isn't a big deal.

Comment: You wrote "OP has a solution at hand". As it is   shown above, the function y[x_] := 1 - Exp[-Abs[x]/l]*(1 + Abs[x]/l) is not any solution of the ODE under consideration since its third and fourth derivatives do not exist at the origin.

Comment: @user64494 OK, then let's call it _so-called solution_. You may query the validness of it, and ask for reference under the question, but that's another story. As mentioned in my last comment, my answer is just a possible deduction, or explanation for the _so-called solution_.

Comment: @xzczd  NDsolve is possible???

Comment: @ABCDEMMM If you mean the technique you learned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202962/1871), don't forget `FiniteElement` can't handle 4th order differential equation directly yet. Rewriting the ODE as a system of lower order ODE may help, but be careful the issue mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172998/1871) may be on the way.

Comment: @xzczd  NDsolve doesnot only include FEM also  FDM or spectral method? or

Comment: @ABCDEMMM There exists no other method that directly handles b.c. inside the domain of definition, AFAIK.

Comment: @xzczd   FDM or spectral method can directly solve fourth order differential equation? e.g.Cahn Hilliard Problems?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Cahn Hilliard Problem is about PDE solving, it's not that related to this post, you'd better start a new question about the topic.

Comment: @xzczd you may check this new post:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204144/solving-ginzburg-landau-equation-in-mma-11-3