# Line-Dirichlet Boundary NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method

I have defined such a Dirichlet boundary conditions which fixes the nodes in a line, however, the results show that only two nodes are fixed, not the nodes in a line,

Code:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] - u[x, y] == 
    0, u[0.5, y] == 1.0}, u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are *boundary* conditions and thus the seen behavior is as expected and correct. Now, you can have `DirichletConditions` inside  the domain: For this you need to generate a mesh with an internal boundary (see documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html))

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {0, 
      1}}, "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 
        4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 1}}], LineElement[{{2, 5}}]}];
```

Look the boundary mesh, which now has an internal boundary:

```
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] - u[x, y] == 
    0, u[0.5, y] == 1.0}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

[image]

You can refine the plot to get a better quality plot like so:

```
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]
However, it is better to just restrict the domain and have the boundary conditions at the boundary like so:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] - u[x, y] == 
     0, u[0.5, y] == 1.0}, u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

[image]

See that they are the same:

```
Plot3D[sol[x, y] - sol2[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: the values on the line are not smooth in MMA... P.S. it has to be ....

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, refine the boundary mesh or the mesh. Could also me a plotting issue. Fact is that the difference between the two plots is small compared to the domain size.

Comment: if I use 1/1000 (global refinement mesh), it is also not smooth, a little better ...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, the try to refine the plot.

Comment: I  have used both methods  ...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, works just fine see update.

Comment: in each element edge, we can observe that the value is not smooth...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, show  me.

Comment: just check my modified post. I add a large zoom figure from 1/100 mesh size

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, that's a picture - I need the code! Try PlotPoints->200 then.

Comment: your modified codes is applied, we can zoom in the figure , see this zoom figure. PlotPoints->200  will not change too much

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, its a plotting articat: `Plot[sol[0.5, y], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0.9999, 1.0001}]`