# NDSolve gives different result if I use NeumannValue to set initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

While trying to get familiar with the NeumannValue function I tried solving the wave equation on $r\in [0,2\pi]$ for $\theta(t,r)$
$$\partial^2_t \theta - \partial^2_r \theta =0, $$
with intial conditions $\theta(0,r)=\sin(r)$, $\partial_t\theta(0,r)=0$ and boundary conditions $\theta(t,0)=\theta(t,2\pi)=0$. The solution can easily be shown to be $\theta(t,r)=\cos(t)\sin(r)$.

However, using NeumannValue on the RHS of the wave equation as I've seen done gives me a solution that differs form this, as you may see by running the animation in my code below.

```
tend = 20.;
rend = 2 Pi;

eq = D[\[Theta][t, r], {t, 2}] - D[\[Theta][t, r], {r, 2}] == NeumannValue[0, t == 0];
ic = {DirichletCondition[\[Theta][0, r] == Sin[ r], True]};
bc = {DirichletCondition[\[Theta][t, 0] == 0, True], DirichletCondition[\[Theta][t, rend] == 0, True]};

sol = NDSolve[Flatten@{eq, ic, bc}, \[Theta], {t, 0, tend}, {r, 0, rend}]

Animate[Plot[{\[Theta][t, r] /. sol, Cos[t] Sin[r]}, {r, 0, rend}, PlotRange -> {{0, rend}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

To compare I also solved it without NeumannValue or Dirichlet Value and got the right behaviour using code below

```
tend = 20.;
rend = 2 Pi;

eq = D[\[Theta][t, r], {t, 2}] - D[\[Theta][t, r], {r, 2}] == 0;
ic = {\[Theta][0, r] == Sin[ r], (D[\[Theta][t, r], t] /. t -> 0) == 
0};
bc = {\[Theta][t, 0] == 0, \[Theta][t, rend] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[Flatten@{eq, ic, bc}, \[Theta], {t, 0, tend}, {r, 0, rend}]

Animate[Plot[{\[Theta][t, r] /. sol, Cos[t] Sin[r]}, {r, 0, rend}, PlotRange -> {{0, rend}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

Comment: You do NOT have `NeumannValue`. This applies to boundary conditions. Your BC are just DirichletCondition on both ends.  So this works `eq = D[\[Theta][t, r], {t, 2}] - D[\[Theta][t, r], {r, 2}] == 0;
ic = {\[Theta][0, r] == Sin[r], (D[\[Theta][t, r], t] /. t -> 0) == 0};
bc = {DirichletCondition[\[Theta][t, 0] == 0, True], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Theta][t, rend] == 0, True]};
sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic, bc}, \[Theta], {t, 0, tend}, {r, 0, rend}]` now both solutions are the same.   `NeumannValue` means the derivative is zero in the spatial domain only. Not in the time domain.

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172972/1871 Don't miss those comments.

Comment: @Nasser "You do NOT have `NeumannValue`. " Nope, the zero Neumann value is on `t==tend` in the first sample.

Comment: @xzczd   I am going by the convention in FEM that NeumannValue are used only with  boundary conditions, not initial conditions. In this problem, BC's are both Dirichlet.

Comment: If you would like to learn about the wave equation, FEM and their relation to Mathematica, then I'd recommend the [Acoustics in the Time Domain tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html)