# How to solve Neumann boundary ODE with shooting method?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

$\rho(x)$ is the distribution function.

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$D_t\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial (v_0\rho)}{\partial x}=0$

$D_t\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}-v_0\rho=0,\ x=1\ \text{or}\ x=-1$

The equation has two solution

(1) $\rho(x)=0$

(2) $\rho(x)=C_1\exp(v_0(x-1))$

I want to get the (2) solution. I try with the shooting method.

```
rWall = 1;
v0[x_] := 1;
Subscript[D, t] = 1
With[{rho = rho[x]}, 
 pde = D[rho v0[x] - Subscript[D, t] D[rho, x], x] == 
    NeumannValue[Sign[x] v0[x] rho, Abs[x] == rWall];] ; usolPoisson =
  NDSolveValue[{pde}, rho, {x, -rWall, rWall}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}}];
```

But the solution is (1) $\rho(x)=0$.

How shall I modify it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does solution (2) really fullfill the two Neumann-conditions?

Comment: yes, I solve the u[x,t] by'With[{rho = rho[x, t]}, 
 pdeold = D[rho, t] + D[rho v0[x] - Subscript[D, t] D[rho, x], x] == 0;
 bc = rho v0[x] - Subscript[D, t] D[rho, x] == 0 /. {{x -> -rWall}, {x -> rWall}};]

usolold = 
  NDSolveValue[{pdeold, ic, bc}, rho, {x, -rWall, rWall}, {t, 0, 100}];' when $t>\infty$ solution 2 is the stable sulution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please notice your statement "The equation has two solution" is improper, because the problem has infinite many solutions, and your solution (1) is just a particular case of solution (2) when $C_1=0$.

Then, your trial doesn't have any effect because, the option setting has actually been ignored in this case. Notice you've already mistakenly write `x` instead of `rho`! To make it more obvious:

```
NDSolveValue[{pde}, rho, {x, -rWall, rWall},
 Method -> {"Shooting", 
   "StartingInitialConditions" -> {rho[rWall] == 酋长!, rho'[rWall] == 我们回部落吧!}}]
```

[image]

I think this should be considered as a bug of error checking of `NDSolve`.

> **Remark**
>
> Inadequate error checking is not rare in `NDSolve`, if you're in
> *v12.3* or earlier, try the following for fun:
>
> ```
> NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 2}, x, {t, 0, 1}, 
>  Method -> {"ExplicitEuler", "兽人!" -> "永不为奴!"}]
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> This is fixed at least since *v13.1*, though.

Then why is the method setting be ignored? Because it's not valid. If you read the document carefully, you'll notice the built-in `Shooting` method solves BVP by searching for the corresponding IVP that satisfies the b.c.s, and IVP solver of `NDSolve` is utilized during the searching process, but `FiniteElement` method is not a IVP solver! Related:

[How to use Finite elements to solve an initial value ODE with NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172972/1871)

"OK, then how to circumvent this?" One choice is, if you still want the built-in `Shooting` method, forget about `FiniteElement`:

```
With[{rho = rho[x]},
  bc = rho - D[rho, x] == 0 /. {{x -> -rWall}, {x -> rWall}}];
NDSolveValue[{pde, bc} /. _NeumannValue -> 0, rho, {x, -rWall, rWall}, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {rho[0] == 1, rho'[0] == 1}}]
ListPlot@%
```

> NDSolveValue::bvluc

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> I've used an undocumented syntax of `ListPlot` here. See [this
> post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273/1871) for more
> info.

Another choice is, forget about `Shooting`, and add a Dirichlet b.c. into `NDSolve`:

```
With[{rho = rho[x]}, 
  pde = D[rho v0[x] - Subscript[D, t] D[rho, x], x] == 
    NeumannValue[-v0[x] rho, True]];
NDSolveValue[{pde, rho[rWall] == 3}, rho, {x, -rWall, rWall}]
Plot[%[x], {x, -rWall, rWall}]
```

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> I've removed the `Sign[x]` because `NDSolve` doesn't handle it
> correctly. I believe it's a bug of `FiniteElement`.

Why can we do this? Because one of the Neumann b.c. is actually redundant. By imposing either of the Neumann b.c., the other Neumann b.c. is automatically satisfied:

```
With[{rho = rho[x]}, eq = D[rho v0[x] - Subscript[D, t] D[rho, x], x] == 0;
 dbc = rho v0[x] - Subscript[D, t] D[rho, x] == 0 /. {{x -> -rWall}, {x -> rWall}};]

DSolve[{eq, dbc[[1]]}, rho, {x, -rWall, rWall}]
(* {{rho -> Function[{x}, E^x C[1]]}} *)
DSolve[{eq, dbc[[2]]}, rho, {x, -rWall, rWall}]
(* {{rho -> Function[{x}, E^x C[1]]}} *)
```

So the simplest way to determine a non-trivial solution is, add a b.c. that's not redundant.