# NDSolve 1D Heat equation with NeumannValue poorly satisfies boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

**Context**

I am trying to measure the slope of the stellar cuspide
around our MilkyWay's central black hole  using the 
 observed [distribution of S stars](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~ghezgroup/gc/animations.html) orbiting around it.

[image]

**Attempt**

Close to the Documentation test case, I am trying to solve 1D PDE corresponding to heat diffusion (bound in a box) of a initially Gaussian Distribution a follows:

with

```
 s = 0.1; a = 0.2; tmax = 5;
```

the solution is found via

```
usol = NDSolveValue[
   eqn = {D[u[x, t], t] - 1/5/tmax^2 D[D[u[x, t], x], x] == 
      NeumannValue[0, True],DirichletCondition[
      u[x, t] == (bound[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[a, s], x]) // 
       Evaluate, t == 0]
     }, u, {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, tmax}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 20
   ];
```

I get an as warning

[image]

while the answer looks reasonable:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[usol[x, t]], {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> tmax/2]
```

[image]

If I check how well the boundary condition is satisfied:

```
Plot[usol[x, 0] - bound[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

which is not great but ok. If I then change 
the integration time:

```
     tmax = 5;
```

Then the same diagnostic yields

[image]

while for `tmax=10` it gets even worse:

[image]

**Question**

> How can make sure the boundary condition is satisfied whatever the time interval over which I want to integrate?

**Attempt to circumvent the problem.**

I have tried using explicitly FEM as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg = Rectangle[{-1, 0}, {1, tmax}];
reg = ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.025, 
   "MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement];
usol2 = NDSolveValue[eqn, u, {x, t} \[Element] reg];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[usol2[x, t]], {x, t} \[Element] reg,  
PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AspectRatio -> tmax/2]
```

[image]

Note the noisy contours, while the two solutions differ somewhat:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[usol2[x, t] - usol[x, t]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The fact that I cannot get the solver to provide me with a good asymptotic solution (at late time) is a problem
because we need to use this late time limit to constrain the galactic center's cuspide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't give a good enough result, because `NDSolve` has chosen pure `FiniteElement` method to solve the problem i.e. `FiniteElement` method has been used for discretization in both $t$ and $x$ direction, while the problem is an initial value problem (IVP) in $t$ direction, and `FiniteElement` method isn't designed for IVP. (I remember [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21) has mentioned this in several places, for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172972/how-to-use-finite-elements-to-solve-an-initial-value-ode-with-ndsolve/172998#comment454454_172972). )

`FiniteElement` method is triggered in $t$ direction because `DirichletCondition` has been used to set the initial condition. Then `FiniteElement` becomes the only choice in $x$ direction, because `NDSolve` cannot combine `TensorProductGrid` and `FiniteElement` at the moment, AFAIK. This topic has been discussed in detail [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/1871).

The following is the fixed code:

```
usol = NDSolveValue[ eqn = {D[u[x, t], t] - 1/5/tmax^2 D[D[u[x, t], x], x] == 0, 
                     u[x, 0] == (bound[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[a, s], x])}, 
                     u, {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
                       Method -> {MethodOfLines, 
                         SpatialDiscretization -> {FiniteElement, 
                           MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}];
```

In this code piece `FiniteElement` is used only in $x$ direction, and `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01` is added to make the mesh denser. `NeumannValue[0, True]` is omitted, because zero Neumann value is the default setting of `FiniteElement` method. This is mentioned in **Details** section of document of `NeumannValue`:

> When no boundary condition is specified on a part of the boundary $∂Ω$, then the flux term $∇·(-c ∇u-α u+γ)+…$ over that part is taken to be $f=f+0=f+\text{NeumannValue}[0,…]$, so not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition.

Actually, as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169895/dirichletcondition-in-ndsolve-causes-asymmetry-finite-element-method/169951#comment446749_169895), even if `NeumannValue[0, whatever]` is added to the code, it will be simply taken out at parser level.