# NDSolve very slow on 2D heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, numerics, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the 2D heat equation

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{t}-u_{x x}-u_{y y}=f \\
u(0, x, y)=\sin (2 \pi x) \sin (2 \pi y) \\
u(t, 0, y)=0 \\
u(t, x, 1)=0 \\
u_{x}(t, 1, y)=2 \pi e^{-t} \sin (2 \pi y) \\
u_{y}(t, x, 0)=2 \pi e^{-t} \sin (2 \pi x)
\end{cases} \quad x \in(0,1), y \in(0,1), t \in(0, T)
$$
where $f=8 \pi^{2} e^{-t} \sin (2 \pi x) \sin (2 \pi y)-e^{-t} \sin (2 \pi x) \sin (2 \pi y)$ using `NDSolve` with the following code.

```
NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
               8 π^2 E^-t Sin[2 π x]*Sin[2 π y] - E^-t Sin[2 π x]*Sin[2 π y], 
u[0, x, y] == Sin[2 π x]*Sin[2 π y],
u[t, 0, y] == 0, u[t, x, 1] == 0, 
Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 1, y] == 2 π E^-t Sin[2 π y], 
Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 0] == 2 π E^-t Sin[2 π x]}, 
u[t, x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

The exact solution is $u(t, x, y)=e^{-t} \sin (2 \pi x) \sin (2 \pi y)$.

I tried using low `PrecisionGoal` (`3`), `AccuracyGoal` (`3`), and `MaxSteps` (`10^4`), but the error is unacceptable, especially on the boundaries.

[image]

Solutions from `NDSolve` are in the first row and the exact solution is in the second.

What would be the best method and options for solving such an equation?

Comment: What is your question? What error were acceptable compared to which solution?

Comment: How long did it take to complete for you? few minutes? much more? can you be more exact. Its been running for me for 5 minutes but still not completed. Also it will be good to say which version you are using.

Comment: @Nasser, When I set `PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3, MaxSteps -> 10^4`, it takes about 10 minutes to complete but it is not close to the exact solution as in the picture.

Comment: You might want to report this to WRI (support@wolfram.com). NDSolve should not hang.

Comment: @Nasser, the model does not hang, at least for me, you can easily see this if you add an evaluation monitor.

Comment: @user21 well, I waited for 40 minutes, so I assumed it hanged :) I am using the original code without the `PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3, MaxSteps -> 10^4`. I am using 13.2 on windows 10.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest solution I find is, add `SolveDelayed -> True` to `NDSolve`:

```
tend = 1; {xL, xR} = {yL, yR} = {0, 1};

sys = {eq, ic, bcx, bcy} = 
   With[{u = u[t, x, y]}, 
    {D[u, t] - Laplacian[u,{x, y}] == 
       8 π^2 E^-t Sin[2 π x] Sin[2 π y] - E^-t Sin[2 π x] Sin[2 π y], 
     u == Sin[2 π x] Sin[2 π y] /. t -> 0, 
    {u == 0 /. x -> xL, 
     D[u, x] == 2 π E^-t Sin[2 π y] /. x -> xR}, 
    {u == 0 /. y -> yL, 
     D[u, y] == 2 π E^-t Sin[2 π x] /. y -> yR}}];

sol = NDSolveValue[sys, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, xL, xR}, {y, yL, yR}, 
    SolveDelayed -> True]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.83636, Null} *)
```

The option `SolveDelayed` is red, but don't worry. Alternatively, you can set `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` or `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> False}`.

---

If you just want to know a solution, you can stop here.

---

Sadly, I can't explain why the method above works. I thought the problem is related to following posts:

[Boundary condition with spatial derivative is ignored by NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871)

[NDSolve uses different difference order for different spatial derivative when solving PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129183/1871)

Nevertheless, even if I discretize the system in the same way (in principle) as that of `NDSolve` using [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871), `NDSolve` behaves differently. The following is the code I use for test:

```
showStatus[status_]:=LinkWrite[$ParentLink,
  SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[]:=showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]
jianshi[t_]:=EvaluationMonitor:>showStatus["t = "<>ToString[CForm[t]]]

mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

points = 50; difforder = 4;
seq := Sequence[sys, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, xL, xR}, {y, yL, yR}, 
   Method -> mol[points, difforder], jianshi[t]];

(* Warning: the following stucks around t = 0.0035 *)
(* sol = NDSolveValue[seq]; // AbsoluteTiming *)
(* $Aborted *)

grid = Array[# &, points, {xL, xR}];
difforder2 = difforder + 1;
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, x, y], t, {grid, grid}, difforder];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[u[t, x, y], t, {grid, grid}, difforder2];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = del /@ del@ptoofunc@eq;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = With[{sf1 = 1, 
    sf2 = 0}, {del /@ ptoofunc2@{diffbc[t, sf1]@bcx[[1]], diffbc[t, sf2]@bcx[[2]]}, 
    ptoofunc2@{diffbc[t, sf1]@bcy[[1]], diffbc[t, sf2]@bcy[[2]]}}];
vars = Outer[u, grid, grid];

seq2 := 
  Sequence[{ode, odeic, odebc}, vars, {t, 0, 1}, jianshi[t], 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}];

sollst = NDSolveValue[seq2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {9.63662, Null} *)

sol2 = rebuild[sollst, {grid, grid}];

{state2} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[seq2];
func2 = state2["NumericalFunction"];

{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[seq];
func = state["NumericalFunction"];

iclst = N@Flatten@Table[ic[[2]], {x, grid}, {y, grid}];

ListLinePlot[func[tend, iclst] - func2[tend, iclst], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> 1. The `showStatus` is from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134793/1871).
> 2. Notice I've defined `odebc` in an unusual way to mimic the behavior of PDE solver of `NDSolve`. To understand why it's defined in this
>    way, please refer to the linked posts above.

As we can see, `func[tend, iclst] - func2[tend, iclst]` (`func` and `func2` are `NumericalFunction` generated by `NDSolve`) is of `10^-12` order, which is likely to be caused by round-off error. Nevertheless, `NDSolve` solves the system generated by `pdetoode` in 10 seconds, but stucks when solving the PDE directly. At this point, the most reasonable explanation for the strange behavior seems to be, `NDSolve` isn't doing a good job in choosing the ODE solver when dealing with the PDE, but:

```
sollst = 
   NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, vars, {t, 0, 1}, jianshi[t], 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve", 
      TimeIntegration -> StiffnessSwitching}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {15.6412, Null} *)

(* Warning: the following is very slow *)
sol = NDSolveValue[sys, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, xL, xR}, {y, yL, yR}, 
    Method -> Append[mol[points, difforder], Method -> StiffnessSwitching], 
    jianshi[t]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This isn't the end. Using the `NumericalFunction` of `state2` to build an equivalent (in principle) ODE system leads to trouble, too!:

```
(* The following stucks around t == 0.003: *)
NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == func2[t, u@t], u[0] == iclst}, u, {t, 0, tend}, 
   jianshi[t]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

So, there seems to be something mysterious in `` NDSolve`StateData ``, but deeper analysis is beyond my reach.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer!

Comment: @xzczd  Nice and interesting answer! I would like to know which Method instead of FiniteElement is used in your `sol` but `sol["MethodInfomation"]` gives no information.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann In this case `TensorProductGrid` is used for spatial discretization. (This can be checked with `state["OptionValues"]`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/1871 ) As to method for time integration, when `SolveDelayed->True` is set, DAE solver  (to be more specific, `IDA` method) has been used.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your helpful explanation!

Answer (score 8):

Try `FiniteElement` method with `NeumannValue` instead of derivative-bc:

```
U = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] - 
     Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
    8 \[Pi]^2 E^-t Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*Sin[2 \[Pi] y] - 
     E^-t Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*Sin[2 \[Pi] y] + 
     NeumannValue[2 \[Pi] E^-t Sin[2 \[Pi] y], x == 1] - 
     NeumannValue[2 \[Pi] E^-t Sin[2 \[Pi] x], y == 0], 
   u[0, x, y] == Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*Sin[2 \[Pi] y], u[t, 0, y] == 0, 
   u[t, x, 1] == 0 }, u , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]

Manipulate[
Plot3D[{U[t, x, y], Exp[-t] Sin[2 Pi x] Sin[2 Pi y]}, {x, 0, 1},{y,0, 1}], {{t, 1/3}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Solution fits good. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is nice. It is weird that NDSolve with default options fails to solve this common equation in a few minutes.

Comment: @Charmbracelet The Method -> FiniteElement is not necessary. See [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1993509248)

Comment: @user21 Your link only shows example with `DirichletConditions` at the boundary. OP question concernes first order derivative boundaries

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, to clarify in *your* answer you do not need the method specification.

Comment: @user21 Thanks! First I misunderstood your comment. Still it is a FEM solution, but option `Method -> FiniteElement`  isn't   necessary(because of `NeumannValue`)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, correct.

Comment: And removing `Method -> "FiniteElement"` will make the code more efficient, because currently you're using pure FEM to solve the problem (including in `t` direction). See this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222373/1871

Comment: I went ahead and removed the Method->"FiniteElement" options. There was a message embezzlement, that we should follow. People will see this, not understand it and make use of it when they should not. Time dependent PDEs should not be solved as a purely spacial problem - that's what you do when you specify Method->"FiniteElement"  because this leads to a convection dominant PDE problem.