# Understanding NDSolve's implementation of the method of lines

Tags: differential-equations, implementation-details

In order to better understand the `MethodOfLines` flag, I tried comparing the results of `NDSolve` for a driven heat equation with a manual implementation based on [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/87074). Despite my best efforts, the absolute discrepancy at collocation points is at the part per million level which seems rather high. Can anyone suggest a strategy to bring `pdetoode` into agreement with `NDSolve` in this case?

**Edit**: Closer examination suggests that the discrepancy may be related to the temporal grid, which contain `10018` and `10007` points for `pdesol` and `odesol` respectively. Is it possible to force the number of temporal grid points into agreement?

```
T = 10;
f[t_] := Sin[t]^2;
numpoints = 30;
grid = Array[# &, numpoints, {0, 1}];
removeredundant = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
xdifforder = 4;

ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[x, t], t, grid, xdifforder];

pde = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] == Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t];
ic = u[x, 0] == 0;
bc = {u[0, t] == f[t], u[1, t] == 0};
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ode = removeredundant@ptoofunc@pde;
odeic = removeredundant@ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;

method = {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MaxPoints" -> numpoints, "MinPoints" -> numpoints, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> xdifforder}};

odesol = NDSolveValue[Join[ode, odeic, odebc], 
                      u /@ grid, {t, 0, T}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001];
pdesol = NDSolveValue[Join[{pde}, {ic}, bc], 
                      u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, Method -> method, 
                      MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 0.001}];

index = Round[numpoints 0.5];
xcoord = grid[[index]];
Plot[{odesol[[index]][t], pdesol[xcoord, t]}, {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> {, Dashed}]
Timing@Plot[odesol[[index]][t] - pdesol[grid[[index]], t], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, the problem is related to the solver in `t` direction. The ODE/DAE solver is the most hard-to-understand part of `NDSolve`, so I cannot give a complete discussion for the topic (at least for now), see analysis in the following post for more info:

[NDSolve very slow on 2D heat equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/278698/1871)

But your specific problem is relatively easy because you just want to avoid the high absolute discrepancy. To achieve this, we simply need to choose exactly the same ODE solver for `NDSolve`.

We first change the following 2 lines

```
odeic = removeredundant@ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;
```

to

```
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
scalefactor = 1;
odebc = diffbc[t, scalefactor]@ptoofunc@bc;
```

With this modification, the `odebc` will become ODEs rather than algebraic equations. (See discussion in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871) for more info. ) Then we can choose a primary ODE solver (whose setting is fully controllable and easy to control) for the system. (There's no such primary DAE solver in `NDSolve` AFAIK. )

```
odemethod = {FixedStep, Method -> ExplicitEuler};
step = 10^-4;

method = {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> numpoints, 
     "MinPoints" -> numpoints, "DifferenceOrder" -> xdifforder}, 
          Method -> odemethod};

odesol = NDSolveValue[Join[ode, odeic, odebc], u /@ grid, {t, 0, T}, 
    StartingStepSize -> step, Method -> odemethod]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.479614, Null} *)
pdesol = NDSolveValue[Join[{pde}, {ic}, bc], u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, 
    Method -> method, StartingStepSize -> {Automatic, step}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.74833, Null} *)

odesol[[index]]["ValuesOnGrid"] - pdesol["ValuesOnGrid"][[index]] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

As we can see, now the error is around `10^-15`, which is likely to be round-off error. If you still feel worried about this error, we can further check with a higher `WorkingPrecision`:

```
odesol = 
   NDSolveValue[Join[ode, odeic, odebc], u /@ grid, {t, 0, T}, 
    StartingStepSize -> step, Method -> odemethod, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {14.0822, Null} *)

pdesol = NDSolveValue[Join[{pde}, {ic}, bc], u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, 
    Method -> method, StartingStepSize -> {Automatic, step}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {18.7217, Null} *)

odesol[[index]]["ValuesOnGrid"] - pdesol["ValuesOnGrid"][[index]] // 
  Abs // Max
(* 0.*10^-16 *)
```

As we can see, with `WorkingPrecision -> 16`, the largest absolute error is `0.*10^-16`, so I think it's safe enough to say the 2 solutions coincide.